Minimum area of the region lies between $ f(x) =x^2-2\displaystyle\int\limits_0^1\big[xg(t)+tg'(t)\big]dt $ and $x$-axis
Let $g:\ [0,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ be a differentiable function and $g(1)=2$. Let $f$ be a function satisfies
$$
f(x) =x^2-2\intop_0^1\big[xg(t)+tg'(t)\big]dt
$$
Suppose $S$ to be the region which lies between the graph of $f$ and the $x$-axis. Then what is the mimimum area of $S$ ?
This is kind of a strange problem that I've never seen. Where do you think I should start from ? May you give me any hints for this ? Besides, what is your opinion about this type of problems ? Thanks.
My solution
We have
\begin{align}
\intop_0^1\big[xg(t)+tg'(t)\big]dt&=x\intop_0^1g(t)dt+\intop_0^1tg'(t)dt
\newline &=x\intop_0^1g(t)dt-\intop_0^1g(t)dt+tg(t)\Big|_0^1
\newline &=(x-1)\intop_0^1g(t)dt+2.
\end{align}
Set $m=\displaystyle\intop_0^1g(t)dt$, one obtains
\begin{align}
f(x)&=x^2-2\big[(x-1)m+2  \big]
\newline &=x^2-2mx+2m-4.
\end{align}
Suppose $a,b$ are the zeros of $f$. This leads to
$$a+b=2m,\ \ \ ab=2m-4.$$
The area of $S$ is given by
\begin{align}
\intop_a^b\big|f(x)\big|dx&=\intop_a^b\big|x^2-2mx+2m-4 \big|dx
\newline &=\intop_a^b\big|x^2-(a+b)x+ab\big|dx.
\end{align}
From here, with some more calculation I think we would figure out the minimum of the area.

Is $ f$ defined at some intervalle ?

@hamam_Abdallah there is no mention of this in the problem,  but I assume the domain of $f$ can be $\mathbb R$.

Are we computing the area of region between $|f|$ and $x$ axis, in between the zeros of $f$? @PermQi

@sam I think so, it's typically so.

Continuing from where you left. Let $a=m-\sqrt{m^2-2m+4}$ and $b=m+\sqrt{m^2-2m+4}$ be the roots of $f$, which always exists for any $m$ as $m^2-2m+4>0$ for all $m \in \mathbb{R}$. Define $$I(m) = \int_a^b |f(x)|dx = \int_{a}^b (x-a)(b-x) dx = \int_{a}^b (-x^2+(a+b)x-ab)dx$$
then this integral can be simplified as $$I(m)=\frac{1}{6}(b-a)^3 = \frac{4}{3}(m^2-2m+4)^{\frac{3}{2}}.$$ This is minimized when $m=1$ with $\min I(m) = 4\sqrt{3}$.

thanks, your solution was interesting
